# Разделить бинарный код по 4 символа

Tags: c++

Я не понимаю как грамотно сделать, что бы при выводе ответа - символы делились по 4 части (не так(10101010) -> а вот так (1010 1010))

```
int main()
{
    int dec, bin = 0;

    cin >> dec;

    for (int j = 0; 0 < dec; j++)
    {
        bin += (dec % 2) * pow(10, j);
        dec /= 2;
    }

    cout << bin << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: Ну наверное для начала стоит научится пользоваться std::bitset, и выводить строки через std::cout << std::bitset<16>{val} << std::endl

Comment: Это яркий пример XY проблемы. Где вы тут увидели "бинарный код"? Ваш код занимается переводом уже готового двоичного числа в десятичное (!), которое "выглядит как двоичное". Это дичайший, полнейший и бесполезнейший бред. "Бинарным кодом" такое никогда не называлось. Этот код - выкинуть на свалку, без разговоров. Формулируйте, что вам нужно сделать с самого начала, и будем начинать решать задачу с начала.

Answer (score 1):

Вынесите  `j` из области цикла (он примет значение  количества цифр в вашем числе, а потом придется работать со строковым представлением числа, если это значение больше `4`:

```
int j = 0;
for (; 0 < dec; j++)
{       
    bin += (dec % 2) * pow(10, j);
    dec /= 2;
}
const int k = 4;
if (j <= k)
    std::cout << bin;
else {           
    std::string sbin = std::to_string(bin);     
    std::cout << sbin.substr(0, k) << ' ' << sbin.substr(k);                
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так - если, конечно, считать, что ваше число влазит в `unsigned char` (8 бит):

```
for(int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
{
    cout << ((dec >> i)&1);
    if (i == 4) cout << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Если полный `unsigned int` - то

```
for(int i = 31; i >= 0; --i)
{
    cout << ((dec >> i)&1);
    if (i%4==0 && i) cout << " ";
}
```

Comment: И при желании можно добавить условие,  чтобы старшие нули не выводились